# Can I use the Windows 10 command prompt to recover some files?

Tags: windows

I'm currently working on a PC that's got a virus. Neither Windows' GUI  loads, nor safe mode. None of the repair options work either.

I was wondering if I could use the command line to move the clients' photos and media to an external HD.

I have full access to the command line but nothing else.

I have to do a factory restore, but my client only wants their photos. Or is there a third-party program to recover them after a factory reset?

There are no restore points either.

Comment: @LotPings When editing, please try to be a little more thorough. Thanks!

Comment: Boot with Windows bootable media, open command prompt from troubleshoot, use `cd /d C:`, you can find files from directories.

Answer (score 1):

If everything works fine from the commandline, you should be able to copy your files to another drive using the command [xcopy](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true) (link is for xp, but should still apply) .

However, be aware, that since your infected operating system is running, the virus could still interfer with the process. It would be better to use some live linux, booted from cd or usb and copy from there. By this way, you also have a GUI and no problems with NTFS security. 
Another alternative would be to remove the hard drive and connect it to another computer. Again, Linux would be optimal, for your security.